# What is the best way to run a long task on Heroku with Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, background-process

I am looking for the best way to run a very long task in Heroku.

I use Ruby On Rails for my web application and I have a very long task that I want to run it every week on Sunday during the night. It takes around 15~20 minutes. I already have [Rufus-Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler), but I am not sure it is the most effective solution.

I also find something about [Backgrounding Tasks in Heroku](http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2013/06/10/backgrounding-tasks-in-heroku-with-delayed-job/) with [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). But is it the best way to handle it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Backgrounding is most suitable for tasks that are triggered by a user of your website, ie situations where your rails app needs to start some jobs which are done asynchronously of the request-response cycle.  It's a much more complicated situation than just running a weekly task independent of your web app eg with Cron or Rufus-scheduler.  What are your reservations about Rufus-scheduler?  On the face of it that seems like a good approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation of what is backgrounding.
I use Rufus-scheduler to update some big data during a period where users (theoretically) don't use the app. But nothing as long as 15-20 minutes.
So, could it be a problem if I use Rufus-Scheduler for such a big task on a production environment based on Heroku ? (free version for now)

Comment: I don't think it's a problem.  if you are worried that its going to use too many system resources, then try slowing it down by doing the task in batches with a sleep inbetween each batch or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I use for a job that I run every night: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

It works really well if your job is configured as a rake task. The guide at the link shows you how to configure everything and even addresses long-running jobs.

Comment: You should definitely do it as a Rake task as @NickM suggests.  The hook from your scheduler into Rails needs to be as simple as possible and Rake is a great solution to that.  Also it allows you to easily test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not recommend to run long-running jobs with Heroku Scheduler.

[Heroku says,](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#long-running-jobs)

> Scheduled jobs are meant to execute short running tasks or enqueue longer running tasks into a background job queue. Anything that takes longer than a couple of minutes to complete should use a worker dyno to run.

So, in my opinion, the best approach would be to use Heroku Scheduler to run rake task for every kind of job (short or long) but if a task takes longer than a couple of minutes then I would simply create a Background Job within that rake task. That way the scheduler will never run longer than a couple of minutes.